# Could not load file or assembly, Oracle.DataAccess v 2.112.3.0

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-assembly

I created a c# app on my win7 laptop and transferred it up to the server to run but am getting a "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=longnumber.

I looked in WINDOWS/Assembly and I do see Oracle.DataAccess there with the same version, culture, and publictokenkey.

Comment: now i'm getting that on my local machine that i built it on too.

Comment: ok...so I think this is happening when I build as a .net 4.0 framework. When I build it as a .net 4.5 framework, it works fine. Why is it doing this only in 4.0 framework?

Answer (score 4):

here is the answer, changed from any cpu to x86 and it works now
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10472469